# node-mssql "connection is closed" when running Mocha test, but runs fine in app

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, node-mssql

I have a node.js data processing app that pulls some data from mssql.  It runs fine and produces the expected results.  However, the integration tests aren't working and I would like them to.

Below is the connection management and a test query function.  I can see from output and running in the debugger that the test has run and failed before the database has connected.  So it seems like my Mocha async setup isn't working, but it looks like everything I've seen in documentation.

node -v
v10.15.0

chai: "^4.2.0",
mocha: "^5.2.0"
mssql: "^4.3.0",

```
const config = require('./config')
const _ = require('underscore')
const sql = require('mssql')

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.error('SQL Error', err)
})

let api = {}

api.connect = async dbConfig => {
    return new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig).connect(
        err => {
            if (err)
                console.error('Connection error', err)
            else
                console.log('connected')
        })
}

var connecting = api.connect(config.sql)

api.simple = async () => {
    let pool = await connecting
    let result = await pool.request().query('select 1 as number')
    return result.recordset[0].number
}

module.exports = api
```

Here is my mocha test for it that fails

```
const { expect } = require('chai')
const data = require('../src/data')

describe('data access', function () {

    it('is simple', async function () {
        const yo = await data.simple()
        expect(yo).to.exist
        expect(yo).to.equal(1)
    })
})
```

I've also tried the older style of async mocha tests using done callbacks ala

```
it('is simple oldschool',  function (done) {
         data.simple()
        .then(function(yo){
            expect(yo).to.exist
            expect(yo).to.equal(1)
            done()
        })
    })
```

That times out no matter how long I set Mocha's timeout for (I tried as high as 60 seconds)

I'm at my wits end here, anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api.connect` can return before the connection is actually done. Rewriting it like this will make sure `ConnectionPool.connect` can finish before the `api.connect` promise resolves.

```
api.connect = dbConfig =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    pool.connect(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Connection error", err);
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(pool);
    });
  });
```

Beyond that, I'm confused about `let pool = await c3`; there's no symbol `c3` in the code you've pasted...

Comment: oops, renamed the c3 to the proper name.  Just a typo when cleaning up for posting.  Fixed my question

Comment: with one little change (return the promise from the api.connect function:) ), that is working.  If you don't mind explaining a little, why did having api.connect async
 and awaiting api.connect(config.sql) not behave the same?

Comment: Because you didn't `await` for `pool.connect` to finish (and you can't, anyway, since it's a callback-based function, not promise-based). My answer is more or less just the boilerplate way to promisify a callback-based function. :)

Comment: Also, I should note that it's probably been sheer luck that this has worked in your app before! So hey, you just fixed a future bug too!

Comment: Haha, thanks for the help and explanation...I suspect the rest of the app took long enough to start up that no db calls were made before the connection was completed

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having a race condition with the database connection.

I do this in the before()

```
before((done) => {
    server.on("serverStarted", function() {
         done();
    });
});
```

Then in my server (I'm using node), I emit when when I am connected:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
var server = http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on port: ' + port);
    db.connect().then(() => {
        console.log("Connect to database successful");
        server.emit("serverStarted") // HERE IT IS
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        console.log("Cannot connect to database");
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. I've pulled out some hair on this one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case its not a web app, its a background processing app.  I did start looking into emitting an event to handle in the before(), but @AKX 's answer is cleaner.